# Why is Conditional Expressions adding new Items to a list view

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to add a Post to a list view, the Home list view has already an Item context.

In my project, a user can add a post and add an item each is a different app with different models.

So In my Home list view, I have my items looped and in each item, it is showing the user related to it.

What I am trying to do is check if this item.user has a post which is `admin_approved=True`related to the user and if it does exist a button show appears in the page linking to another page with these posts.

So if there are Zero posts related to the user or posts available but  `admin_approved=False` or **not yet** `admin_approved=True` the button should not appear but if there is 1 or more posts that are `admin_approved=True`the button should appear.

I have tried to annotate the queryset but the issue is that when a user has 2 posts one which is approved and another not approved, 2 items appears one with the button and one without the button and duplication takes place in the homepage List view

I have tried to use .distinct() but it didn't work items are still duplicated

Here is the models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    designer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    admin_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

here is the views

```
from .models import Item
from django.db.models import Case, When, BooleanField, Q

class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Item
    paginate_by = 12
    template_name = "home.html"
    ordering = ['-timestamp']

    def get_queryset(self):
        has_post = Case(
            When(Q(designer__post__isnull=False) & Q(designer__post__admin_approved=True), then=True),
            default=False,
            output_field=BooleanField()
        )
        return super().get_queryset().annotate(has_post=has_post).distinct()
```

here is the template

```
{% for item in object_list %}
    {{ item.title }}
    {% if item.has_post %}
        SHOW BUTTON
    {% else %}
        HIDE BUTTON
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

here is the item model

```
class Item(models.Model):
    designer = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: It will repeat the same `Item` for each `designer__post` combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will repeat each `Item` for each `designer__post` combination, since you do not use a "fold" function.

You can make use of an [**`Exists`** subquery [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries) instead:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Item
    paginate_by = 12
    template_name = "home.html"
    ordering = ['-timestamp']

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).annotate(
            has_post=Exists(
                Post.objects.filter(
                    designer_id=OuterRef('designer_id'),
                    admin_approved=True
                )
            )
        )
```